# Getting chat id by row on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-4

I have a table filled with data. I have displayed it but now when I click on the History button on each row, to get chat_id of that row and pass it to controller. So far I am passing an array of IDs but I cant make it work.

Below is my code so far:

//views

```
<?php $arr = 0; ?>
    @foreach($chat as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->chat_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->fullname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->plaintext }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->transcript_text }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->duration }}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" name="history" onclick="javascript:getID('{{$row->chat_id}}','{{$arr}}')">History</button>
                <input name="recordid[]" id="recordid[]" type="hidden">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $arr++; ?>
    @endforeach
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getID(id, arr){
            $('[id^=recordid]').eq(arr).val(id);
        }
    </script>
```

//controller

```
public function showMessage(){
    $id = Input::get('recordid');
    $history = Chat::where('chat_id','=', $id)->get();
    return View::make('chat.chatview')->with(array('history'=>$history));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of your array what you gives to your Template is history `with(array('history'=>$history));` and not chat `@foreach($chat as $row)` loop through history `@foreach($history as $chat)` to get result

Comment: @foreach($chat as $row) is the data that I have displayed and here I have the submit button history which is supposed to get me to another template with the chat_id of that particular row.
This is the other template:
<div class="container">
    <h1 style="color: white;">Chat History</h1>
    <?php if (isset($history)) { ?>
           @foreach($history as $row)
           
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td>{{$row->transcipt_text}}</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
           @endforeach
    <?php } ?>
    
</div>

Comment: than tell me please where is the $chat aray in your code ? where it is Defined? you loop through array what is not defined in your template or in your code

Comment: I am getting the chat model in the route 
Route::get('individual', function(){
    $chat = Chat::all();
    return View::make('chat/individual')->with('chat', $chat);});

Comment: maybe View::make('chat/individual')->with(array('chat' => $chat);}) ???